# How do I replicate Adidas product page's "two way sticky menu"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

I am trying to replicate what I can best describe as a "two way sticky menu" which Adidas is using on their product pages as seen here: https://www.adidas.com/us/campus-00s-shoes/GY9473.html

On their product page, the aside menu on the right hand side has the following effects:

- The bottom of the aside menu is sticking to the bottom of the viewport when scrolling down.
- The top of the aside menu is and sticking to the top of the viewport when scrolling up.

What I have so far works sometimes when scrolling all the way down and up, however, if you change scrolling direction before getting to the top or bottom it snaps to a different position for some reason (which is NOT desireable). Here is my code so far:

```js
var prev_scroll_pos = 0;
const right_content = document.getElementById("right_content");
window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
    const curr_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (prev_scroll_pos > curr_scroll_pos) {
        // up
        right_content.style.top = "0";
        right_content.style.bottom = "auto";
        right_content.style.alignSelf = "flex-start";
    } else {
        // down
        right_content.style.top = "auto";
        right_content.style.bottom = "0";
        right_content.style.alignSelf = "flex-end";
    }
    prev_scroll_pos = curr_scroll_pos;
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 500vh;
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}

.main_container {
    background-color: lightsalmon;
    height: 300vh;
}
.main_content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100%;
}

.aside_container {
    background-color: #eee;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}
.aside_content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: pink;
    height: 150vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0rem;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="main_container">
        <div class="main_content">
            <span>Main Content Start</span>
            <span>Main Content Middle</span>
            <span>Main Content End</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="aside_container">
        <div class="aside_content" id="right_content">
            <span>Aside Content Start</span>
            <span>Aside Content Middle</span>
            <span>Aside Content End</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```